# How can I convert jpg file to pbm file through only matrix operation?

Tags: matlab, image-conversion

I have tried the method as follows, but it didn't work so efficient.

```
for i = 1:h 
            for j = 1:w 
                Img(1,(i-1)*aligned_w+j) = (Matrix(i,j)&1);
                %fwrite(file,1-Matrix(i,j),'ubit1');
            end
            for j = 1:align
                %fwrite(file,0,'ubit1');
                Img(1,(i-1)*aligned_w+w+j)=0;
            end
        end
        fwrite(file,Img,'ubit1');
```

the result of above code is off track compared to the imwrite(imread('*.jpg','jpg'),'*.pbm','pbm'), can anyone tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm found the solution, the reason is that Matrix should be a w*h*channel matrix, the format (i,j) should be replaced into (i,j,channel), where channel from 1 to 3. And the result should be the three expression under or operation.